# Google Cloud Function: lazy loading not working

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I deploy a google cloud function with lazy loading that loads data from google datastore. The last update time of my function is 7/25/18, 11:35 PM. It works well last week.

Normally, if the function is called less than about 30 minutes since last called. The function does not need to load data loaded from google datastore again. But I found that the lazy loading is not working since yesterday. Even the time between two function is less than 1 minute.

Does anyone meet the same problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud Functions can fail due to several reasons such as uncaught exception and internal process crashes, therefore, it is required to check the [logs files / HTTP responses](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#errors) error messages to verify the issue root cause and determine if the function is being restarted and generating [Function execution timeouts](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout) that could explain why your function is not working.

I suggest you take a look on the [Reporting Errors](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/error-reporting) documentation that explains the process required to return a function error in order to validate the exact error message thrown by the service and return the error at the recommended way. Keep in mind that when the errors are returned correctly, then the function instance that returned the error is labelled as behaving normally, avoiding [cold starts](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#cold_starts) that leads higher latency issues, and making the function available to serve future requests if need be.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Actually, my function works well expect lazy loading. Unfortunately, logs does not show any error ...

Comment: In this case, you can use the [Logging Pipeline Messages](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/logging#adding-log-messages-to-your-pipeline) functionality to get further visibility of your pipeline running flow as well as the [Monitoring Interface](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/dataflow-monitoring-intf) to view the error logs and the [logs emitted by your pipeline](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/logging#monitoring-pipeline-logs).